# How to specify columns when using repeated indices with numpy [for use with np.add.at()]

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing, array-broadcasting

I'm trying to apply an addition operator to an array where I want repeated indices to indicate repeated addition operations. From a Python Data Science Book (https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/02.07-fancy-indexing.html), it seems that this is possible using `np.add.at(original matrix, indices, thing to add)`, but I can't figure out how to specify the indices to operate on columns, not rows.

e.g. Dummy Example

```
# Create Array
A = np.arange(12)
A = A.reshape(4,3)
print(A)
```

gives

```
[[ 0  1  2]
 [ 3  4  5]
 [ 6  7  8]
 [ 9 10 11]]
```

and

```
# Create columns to add to A (in reality, all values won't be the same)
B = np.ones_like(A[:, [0,0]])
print(adder)
```

gives

```
[[1 1]
 [1 1]
 [1 1]
 [1 1]]
```

I want to perform the operation `A[:, [0, 0]] += B` but using the system where repeated indices indicate repeated operations (so in this case, both columns of B gets added to column 0). The result should thus be:

```
[[ 2  1  2]
 [ 5  4  5]
 [ 7  7  8]
 [ 11 10 11]]
```

This can be done using `np.add.at(A, I, B)` I believe, but how do I specify the indices `I` to correspond to `[:, [0,0]]` as this gives a syntax error (it seems that the indices matrix can't contain the `:` character?).

Thanks

Comment: The docs say `I` can be a tuple that contains slice objects.  My guess is that `(slice(None),[0,0])` should work.  Can't test it right now.

Comment: Thanks, that does work. If you put that as an answer (ideally with some explanation re. how slicing none works please?), then I can accept. Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [12]: A = np.arange(12).reshape(4,3)
In [13]: np.add.at(A, (slice(None), [0,0]), 1)
In [14]: A
Out[14]: 
array([[ 2,  1,  2],
       [ 5,  4,  5],
       [ 8,  7,  8],
       [11, 10, 11]])
```

This could also be written with `s_` as

```
np.add.at(A, np.s_[:, [0,0]], 1)
```

`s_` is a class object that lets us using indexing notation to create the necessary tuple.  In an indexing context Python interpreter converts the `:` into a `slice` object.

```
In [19]: np.s_[:, [0,0]]
Out[19]: (slice(None, None, None), [0, 0])
```